# Port Qt to On-Time RTOS-32

Tags: qt, rtos

I would like to know if there is some port of QT for On-Time RTOS-32.

Is there any place where I can found more information about this kind of port?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Guillermo

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply use On-Time's own [RTPEG-32](http://www.on-time.com/rtpeg-32.htm) GUI library?

There is a slide presentation on porting Qt to an RTOS [here](http://www.slideshare.net/qtbynokia/qt-on-real-time-operating-systems), but is a bit general perhaps.  You would need at least a pthread implementation for RTOS-32 since that is what the Qt source uses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed we are evaluating right now the RTPEG-32 library.